# Overlay for table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I an trying to create an overlay for table rows. I want the overlay to show after the user's mouse has been on the row for a second or so, and remove it once the mouse has left the row.
I started working on this: http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/

I am stuck on several things:

1. The mouseenter event keeps firing when moving the mouse inside the row. I can't figure out why.
2. I want the overlay to cover the row, except for the image TD, and haven’t had much success with that either.
3. I want each row to have different text / buttons on the overlay. I tried adding a div to each TR and using `.parent().('.overlay')`, but couldn't get that to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

**Edit:** After some pointers, here is a working Fiddle with all my requirements met: http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/37/

**Edit 2:** I ended up going with the hoverIntent jquery plugin, since it solves the glitch issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you for the first question: you should use **mouseover** instead of **mouseenter** see [this link](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) for more informations, basically mouseover triggers only for current div when mouseenter triggers for current div and all parents, so moving the mouse keeps firing the parent div's mouseenter.

**Edit** : <s>oh! and keep mouseleave to trigger the overlay.hide</s>

You should bind the overlay.hide to overlay.mouseleave.(i.e. when mouse leaves the overlay, not the row since the overlay is in front of it)

**Edit** : here is the update, http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/32/ see I put right:'0px', width:'66,7%' in the Overlay.css so it would leave the image free.

As you'll see there is a glitch when you mouseleave the overlay to the other one for the overlay moves, completes the slideup transition and then slides down again after one sec.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the fiddle. Now I see another issue. When I move from one row to another, but that might be solved when using different divs for each row.

Comment: yes, that's I think because the same overlay ends its slideup transition before taking the new slidedown.

Comment: Thank you! Two out of three :) I added .stop() to the mouseover event in order to stop the glitch. Here is the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/36/